# Парсинг уравнения regex

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Добрый вечер. Помогите подправить регулярное выражение. Необходимо распарсить часть уравнения, примерно такого вида  : `5+10+2+-1`. Вся проблема в числах с отрицательными значениями. Вот выражение которое есть :

```
(?<firs>-?[\d.,]+)(?<operator>[*\-+/])(?<second>-?[\d.,]+)
```

Приведенный выше пример разбирает без проблем. Но уравнение такого вида `5+10-2+-1` парсит неправильно. Собственно в месте где 10-2 считает, что (2) это -2.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно изменить в выражении, что бы разбор проходил правильно?

Comment: Вам нужно написать обычный леворекурсивный парсер. А регулярные выражения здесь немного не уместны.

Comment: @KoVadim, похоже на них свет клином сошелся.

Comment: Леворекурсивный парсер не подойдет если есть приоритеты. В случае с приоритетами самое простое - магазинный автомат

Comment: Почему же не подойдёт? Построение подобного парсера возможно. Однако с меньшими усилиями можно разобрать выражение по расширенной БНФ, что делается элементарным рекурсивным спуском.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Вполне можно вычислять и регулярными выражениями.
Можно даже соблюдать абсолютно все приоритеты выполнения операций.

Как я понял автор вопроса хочет:

1. Находить пары чисел разделенных оператором
2. Находить значение выражения для этой пары чисел
3. Подставлять вместо найденного текста новое число
4. Применять пункт 1, пока все не упростится до одного числа

Я приведу пример, как это сделать просто для четырех операторов, далее можно бесконечно усложнять регулярное выражение организуя поддержку скобок и других операторов.

```
/^(?:(-?\d+)([*\/+-])(-?\d+)$|.*?(\d+)([*\/])(-?\d+)|.*?(\d+)([+-])(-?\d+))/
```

Тестировал выражение в JavaScipt, поэтому нет именованных групп, а они очень пригодятся для сложного регулярного выражения вместе с рекурсивными ссылками (все это есть в С#).

Смысл выражения очень прост первый приоритет на замену отдаем двум числам с любыми знаками, разделенных любым оператором, если весь текст состоит только из этих двух чисел.

```
(-?\d+)([*\/+-])(-?\d+)$
```

Второй приоритет имеют операторы деления и умножения

```
.*?(\d+)([*\/])(-?\d+)
```

И низший приоритет у сложения и вычитания

```
.*?(\d+)([+-])(-?\d+)
```

Приоритеты создаются путем привязки регулярного выражения к началу текста и порядка расположения альтернатив в регулярном выражении.
В зависимости от того, какой приоритет сработал будут матчиться группы 1-3, 4-6 или 7-9. Нет разницы какие группы сматчились. Результат будет всегда одинаков: число1 оператор число2.

---

Рассмотрим как будет пошагово преобразован текст `5+10-2+-1` по такому алгоритму:

```
5+10-2+-1 => 15-2+-1  
15-2+-1   => 13+-1  
13+-1     => 12
```

В результате замен будут появляться последовательности операторов вроде `-+-` и.т.п. В таком случае необходимо предварительно искать такие последовательности и менять их на один оператор.

---

## Внимание

Регулярное выражение выше несет учебный характер. В сниппете ниже Вы найдете код вычисляющий с учетом скобок, упрощающий последовательности операторов, поэтому там совершенно другое регулярное выражение, но введя туда арифметическое выражение Вы вычислите его с помощью регулярных выражений ;)
Не забудьте посмотреть консоль- туда выводится порядок упрощения исходного выражения.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function defined() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
      if (typeof(arguments[i]) !== "undefined") return arguments[i];
    return arguments[0];
  };

  $("#run").click(function() {
    var replacer = function() {
      var num1 = defined(arguments[2], arguments[6], arguments[10]);
      var operator = defined(arguments[3], arguments[7], arguments[11]);
      var num2 = defined(arguments[4], arguments[8], arguments[12]);
      var before = defined(arguments[1], "");
      var before2 = defined(arguments[5], arguments[9], "");
      return before + before2 + eval(num1 + operator + num2);
    };
    var clearOperators = function(text) {
      return text.replace(/[+-]{2,}/g, function(val) {
        return (val.replace(/\+/g, "").length % 2 == 0) ? "+" : "-";
      }).replace(/([*\/])\++/g, "$1");
    };
    var text = $("#text").val();
    var re = /^(.*\((?=[^\)]*\))|)(?:(-?\d+)([*\/+-])(-?\d+)(?=(?:$|\)))|(.*?)(\d+)([*\/])(-?\d+)|(.*?)(\d+)([+-])(-?\d+))/;
    var oldLength = -1;
    while (!/^-?\d+$/.test(text) && oldLength != text.length) {
      oldLength = text.length;
      text = clearOperators(text);
      text = text.replace(/\(([+-]?\d+)\)/g, "$1");
      text = clearOperators(text);
      if (text.length != oldLength) console.log(text);
      text = text.replace(re, replacer);
      console.log(text);
    }
    $("#result").html(text);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<INPUT id="text" value="5+(4-1)*-4*(3+(-5+1)/2)" />=
<SPAN id="result"></SPAN>
<BR/>
<BUTTON id="run">Вычислить</BUTTON>
```

Comment: У меня не заматчило 5++10: https://regex101.com/r/sZ8jT6/1

Comment: @VladD Ну, JavaScript например выдаст ошибку синтаксиса. Другие языки наверно тоже. Можно включить и поддержку таких ошибочных конструкций, но мне кажется это лишнее для парсера таких выражений.

Comment: Хм, и правда, не компилируется. Но `5+ +10` [компилируется](http://ideone.com/mBMsKl), но не [парсится](https://regex101.com/r/sZ8jT6/2).

Comment: @VladD добавил сниппет. Там длинные последовательности плюсов и минусов приводятся к одному оператору из учета, что два минуса дают плюс.

Comment: Хм. `10+ +2` (и `10- -2`) вроде не считает. // И `5*+8` (а вот `5*-8` считает).

Comment: Но вообще да, разбор арифметических выражений с приоритетами на чистых регулярках впечатляет.

Comment: @VladD оцените - добавил поддержку скобок и упрощения `*+` или `/+`

Comment: Ох! «Достаточно продвинутая технология неотличима от магии» (с)

Answer (score 1):

Регулярные выражения непригодны для подобных задач (подробнее см. [иерархию Хомского](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%A5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)). Однако, [РВ-грамматики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0,_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) уже позволяют разбор подобных выражений.

Простой пример подобной грамматики: http://pegjs.org/online

Реализации РВ-грамматик существуют для многих языков, включая C# (например, http://otac0n.com/Pegasus/).