# Регулярные выражения в Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

я хочу сделать программу которая считывает строку (формула), что необходимо сделать чтобы перевести эту строку на "язык компьютера"?))

К примеру есть такая строка:

```
"y=ln(x)+2.5*7^x"
```

необходимо чтобы эти действия выполнялись в программе.

Читал что это можно сделать с помощью регулярных выражений, но не понял как.

Comment: для этого вам нужен не Регулярное выражение а программа (или модуль программы) который выполняет формулу из строки. попробуйте прочитать про MathLab или MathCad или Maple

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/110941/ здесь есть ответ, как это можно сделать при помощи регулярных выражений, НО не нужно.