# Почему в регулярном выражении образуется бесконечный цикл?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Почему в регулярном выражении образуется бесконечный цикл?

```
var str2 = '(x + y) * (x - y)';
var reg2 = /\(.*\)/;
var match2;

while (match2 = reg2.exec(str2)) {
  console.log(match2);        
}
```

Comment: Если ответ на ваш вопрос дан правильный ответ - отметьте его как правильный, пожалуйста

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Почему вечный цикл?

   Потому что регулярное выражение без флага `g` и оно каждый раз сопоставляется с начала строки. Чтобы цикл перебирал все вхождения (и завершался присваиванием `null`) надо добавить флаг `g`:

   ```
   var reg2 = /\(.*\)/g;
   ```
2. Почему вместо всех подвыражений находит всю строку целиком?

   Потому что поиск жадный. Чтобы получить нежадный поиск, надо добавить `?` после `*`:

   ```
   var reg2 = /\(.*?\)/g;
   ```
3. Почему не работает что-нибудь ещё?

   Потому что не надо парсить арифметические выражения регулярками. Следует написать нормальный линейный парсер. А регулярками можно разбить строку на токены.

Comment: Пример 2 кажется не завершится никогда

Comment: @AlexeyTen, почему?

Comment: А, чёрт, я скобки пропустил. Вернее подумал что они группирующие

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо. А что значит линейный парсер? А парсер регуляркоми тогда это какой?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский - метчется от match :)

Comment: @gilo1212, тот, который работает за один проход по строке. Или по списку токенов. Выделить список токенов, а потом его парсить - пожалуй, наиболее удобный вариант.

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо. `тот, который работает за один проход по строке.` - не могли бы Вы привести минимальный пример?  Не могли бы Вы почомь по этому вопросу - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526986/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Можно и регулярками, если сильно захотеть http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433787/481

Comment: @Qwertiy аааа. я в смысл и не вникал) ну все равно имхо тогда мАтчится ужжж) так понятнее... даже мЭтчится непонятно, хоть и произносится по-английски так